# Simple materials created using node view not rendered

Tags: materials, node-editor

I'm trying to create a material. I was unable to use more complex mixing - it just didn't show up - but even simpler nodes aren't being applied to the mesh. I am in cycles render and the Viewport finder only provides solid colors, not the complex color I wanted. Even when I click "Render image" or assign it doesn't show up. It's just grey. Tutorials aren't helping. [image: Viewport][image: node view]

Comment: Which "Render Image" did you click? The one at the bottom of the 3D view?

Comment: Can you post your blend file? Questions like this can be hard to answer without being able to see how your scene is set up.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to change viewport colors of the object's material (which is written above the option in the first screenshot). Nodes don't and shouldn't have any effect on them, they define color of materials which will be rendered and these are shown only in Rendered shading mode (and approximation of that in Material mode)

Comment: @seaturtle: I clicked the one at the top of the 3d view.

Comment: @Brenticus: I'm not sure how. I'll try to figure that out...

Comment: Well, if it wasn't in a menu, you clicked the wrong one. That one just renders a "screenshot" of the 3D View. For an actual render, you can hit F12 or use the Render menu, or to see what your material looks like, hit Shift+Z.